# Change Color of Icon When Hovering Over Adjacent Text With jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have seen [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740562/change-color-of-icon-when-hovering-over-div-in-which-it-is-contained) but I want to change the color of the icon with JavaScript instead.

Trying to write a function that changes the color of the icon *and* the text when the icon *or* the text is hovered over.

I'm using the code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981463/detect-if-hovering-over-element-with-jquery) to check to see if the element is hovered with jQuery:

```js
function changeIconColor (hoverState) {
let contactText = document.getElementsByClassName('contact-text');
let contactIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('contact-icon');  
//if the text is hovered over, change the color of the icon to #e46e6e
if ($('#contact-text').is(":hover")) {
    contactIcon.css("color", "red");
};
if ($('#contact-icon').is(":hover")) {
    contactText.css("color", "red");
};
}

changeIconColor();
```

```css
.outer-one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.outer-two {
  display: flex;
}

.phone-text, .contact-text {
  color: #213b56;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.contact-text {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.contact-text:hover {
  color: #e46e6e;
}

.user-icon, .contact-icon {
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

   <div class="outer-one">
   <div class="outer-two">
   <i class="far fa-user user-icon"></i>
   <span class="phone-text" style="font-family: Raleway, sans-serif; font-size: 
                                1.2rem;">(314) 567-7000  | </span>
   <i class="far fa-envelope contact-icon" id="contact-icon"></i>
   <a class="contact-text" href="http://cfk2021.flywheelsites.com/" id="contact-text">CONTACT</a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see, I'm loading jQuery in the `<head>` of the `html`, so I'm not sure why I'm getting a script error. Or check out this [jSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6L5tbwq/6/) for reference.

Comment: You have no elements with an id contactText or contactInfo

Comment: Oh - thought since I created those variables within the function that would work - let me fix that.

Comment: I was curious if I could get a more descriptive error message so i plugged it in codepen and it doesn't register an error

Comment: I'm not getting the error at all anymore after adding ID's as @Rojo suggested. It's just that now, the function isn't doing anything.

Comment: You need to add `[0]` after `contactIcon` and `contactIcon` since `getElementsByClassName` returns a list

Comment: It looks like it's only being called at page startup

Comment: Your problem appears to be that your only calling your function on start-up, it needs to be called when the mouse moves over or away from the elements, you should use `"mouseenter"` and `"mouseleave"` events

Comment: since version of March 9, 2014 , the hover pseudo selector is not supported in jquery , you should use hover() function , see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function changeIconColor (hoverState) {
    let contactText = document.getElementsByClassName('contact-text')[0];
    let contactIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('contact-icon')[0];  
    //if the text is hovered over, change the color of the icon to #e46e6e
    if ($('#contactText').is(":hover")||$('#contactIcon').is(":hover")) {
      contactText.style.color = "red";
      contactIcon.style.color = "red";
    } else {
      contactText.style.color = "black";
      contactIcon.style.color = "black";
    }
}
document.getElementsByClassName('contact-text')[0].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
    changeIconColor();
});
document.getElementsByClassName('contact-text')[0].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
    changeIconColor();
});
document.getElementsByClassName('contact-icon')[0].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
    changeIconColor();
});
document.getElementsByClassName('contact-icon')[0].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
    changeIconColor();
});
```

```css
.outer-one {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .outer-two {
      display: flex;
    }

    .outer-three {
      display: flex;
    }

    .phone-text, .contact-text {
      color: #213b56;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: 'Raleway';
      margin-top: 4px;
    }

    .contact-text {
      margin-top: 7px;
    }

    .contact-text:hover {
      color: #e46e6e;
    }

    .user-icon, .contact-icon {
      padding: 7px;
    }
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class="outer-one">
  <div class="outer-two">
    <i class="far fa-user user-icon"></i>
    <span class="phone-text" style="font-family: Raleway, sans-serif; font-size: 
                                    1.2rem;">(314) 567-7000  | </span>
    <i class="far fa-envelope contact-icon" id = "contactIcon"></i>
    <a class="contact-text" id = "contactText" href="http://cfk2021.flywheelsites.com/">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should do the trick
I just made the edits mentioned in the comments, then put `changeIconColor` into event handlers for the elements to update the colors every time the mouse entered or exited the element boundaries, I think this might be easier in CSS but I'm not big on CSS

Comment: This is very close but the idea is that both elements - the envelope and text - both need to become red when _either_ one is hovered over. Made some adjustments and now it works when the envelope is hovered over, but not the text: https://jsfiddle.net/nLg5y8o6/1/

Comment: oh, I get it :) I'll fix that

Comment: ok, @HappyHands31 by the way for the fix I just copied your little chunk for the if statements to save a little work, just thought I ought to credit you for that :)

Comment: It's still turning both elements red when you hover over the envelope, but only turning the text red when you hover over the text. It needs to turn both the text _and_ the envelope red when you hover over the text, if possible.

Comment: ok got it :D still just confused about what you need sorry

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong pseudo selector on jQuery, thus the error.

Use [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead to change color, knowing that it has two function as parameter, first for `mouseenter` and second for `mouseleave`.

See the below snippet :

### 1- hover apply on same text and icon ( shorter version ) :

```js
$(function() {
  $('.contact-text, .contact-icon').hover(
    function() {
      $('.contact-text, .contact-icon').css("color", "#e46e6e");
    },
    function() {
      $('.contact-text, .contact-icon').css("color", "#213b56");
    }
  )
});
```

```css
.outer-one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.outer-two {
  display: flex;
}

.outer-three {
  display: flex;
}

.phone-text,
.contact-text {
  color: #213b56;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.contact-text {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.contact-text:hover {
  color: #e46e6e;
}

.user-icon,
.contact-icon {
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="outer-one">
  <div class="outer-two">
    <i class="far fa-user user-icon"></i>
    <span class="phone-text" style="font-family: Raleway, sans-serif; font-size: 
                                    1.2rem;">(314) 567-7000  | </span>
    <i class="far fa-envelope contact-icon"></i>
    <a class="contact-text" href="http://cfk2021.flywheelsites.com/">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 2- hover applied separatly on text & icon :

```js
//
let $contactText = $('.contact-text');
let $contactIcon = $('.contact-icon');

$contactText.hover(
  function() {
    $contactIcon.css("color", "#e46e6e");
  },
  function() {
    $contactIcon.css("color", "#213b56");
  }
)

$contactIcon.hover(
  function() {
    $contactText.css("color", "#e46e6e");;
  },
  function() {
    $contactText.css("color", "#213b56");
  }
)
```

```css
.outer-one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.outer-two {
  display: flex;
}

.outer-three {
  display: flex;
}

.phone-text,
.contact-text {
  color: #213b56;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.contact-text {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.contact-text:hover {
  color: #e46e6e;
}

.user-icon,
.contact-icon {
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="outer-one">
  <div class="outer-two">
    <i class="far fa-user user-icon"></i>
    <span class="phone-text" style="font-family: Raleway, sans-serif; font-size: 
                                    1.2rem;">(314) 567-7000  | </span>
    <i class="far fa-envelope contact-icon"></i>
    <a class="contact-text" href="http://cfk2021.flywheelsites.com/">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is much simpler solution because of jQuery so it's probably better than mine

Comment: @OtherMe no great difference except code length ;)